# C++ Initialize object with with non-const variable template

Tags: c++, oop, templates, object

I have an object with this type of template:

```
RTree<int, float, 2, float> tree;
```

The third argument is the number of dimensions my tree will have. I want this to change each time a new tree is created. How can I replace the number with a variable which changes each time? The compiler throws an error with non-const variables.

Comment: You simply can't do that. I think you need to ask a different question.

Comment: Are you trying to change it at runtime? That's not possible, you need to specify the template non-type parameter *before* the program runs, at compile time.

Comment: I create different objects each time depending on a file I read. The problem is that the file has each time different number of dimensions so I need a different tree each time. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: How is the third parameter used in the class template? If it were to become a member variable, can your class template work properly? If so, that's the best option. If not, you'll have to rethink your design.

Comment: Yes it seems that there is no reason to be there. It is a library I'm using for my project. I'll probably make it a member value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change a template parameter at run time.

---

If your intention is to change the number of tree dimensions with each new deceleration of tree at *compile time* then you may be able to do this:

```
RTree<int, float, __COUNTER__, float> tree;
```

Although this would be, in my mind, of limited use.

---

If your intention is to change it at runtime, then consider keeping count in the `RTree` class or through a constructor argument so you can specify the dimension of the tree.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will create an argument in the constructor. I thought I was doing something wrong because I'm using a library.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how templates work and cannot be accomplished in this way.  They are for writing code that works independent of any particular *type* not *value*.  You say you

> "want this to change each time a new tree is created"

so then just give the constructor a parameter that accepts an integer and go from there.